# STM32: Is it possible to write data to flash memory by using system bootloader when write protection is on?

Tags: stm32, bootloader, flash-memories

When I try to program with STM32 flash loader and if the write protection is on, it want erase all of the memory. Probably because of program drop the security level so MCU erase all of the data. But can I write a data without disturbing write protection and keep the piece of the flash memory intact?

Possible MCU: [STM32f072xx](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f072c8.pdf) or [STM32f103xx](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00171190-stm32f101xx-stm32f102xx-stm32f103xx-stm32f105xx-and-stm32f107xx-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Comment: Which specfic STM32 model you are talking about? They are all different.

Comment: I looked at the STM32F072, The options are 64KB or 128 KB. Do you know if the memory is divided into sectors? Can you share the flash memory organization?

Comment: Yes, its 64KB one and memory divided by 2KB pages... 2 page = 1 sector